# RavenDb. Sorting syntax in Lucene query using Index

Tags: lucene, ravendb

I am trying to write Lucene query in RavenDB Index which will return results sorted by some field.

But still no success.

The Query looks like:

> **Language:EN** AND **Key:*car*** AND **sort=KEY**

**Question:**

Is it possible at all to add sorting statement in query?
If yes, how the sorting syntax looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The sort parameter is passed along with the query, but not within the query. If you're using the C# client API you'll have an operator OrderBy, otherwise you're most likely using the REST API, in which the sort parameter is being passed as an additional URL parameter